# Formula for composition of pull back

Tags: differential-geometry

Problem says:

> $(GF)^{*}=F^{*}G^{*}$  , that is, for any form $\xi$   on $P$  ,
>   $(GF)^{*}(\xi)=F^{*}(G^{*}(\xi))$

So, by hint, I showed 0-form and 1-form cases.

Let $f$
  be a function on $P$
 . Then $(GF)^{*}(f) = f(GF)
 = (fG)F
 = (G^{*}(f))F
 = F^{*}(G^{*}(f))$

Now, let $\varphi$
  be a 1-form on $P$
 . Then $F^{*}G^{*}(\varphi)(v)$   $= F^{*}(\varphi(G_{*}(v)))$
    $= \varphi(G_{*}F_{*}(v))$
    $= \varphi((GF)_{*}(v))$
    $= (GF)^{*}(\varphi)(v)$

So, it remains to show that it holds for any 2 form on $M$.

I tried as follows:

$(GF)^{*}(\eta)(v,w)$  $= \eta((GF)_{*}(v),(GF)_{*}(w))$
    $= \eta(G_{*}F_{*}(v),G_{*}F_{*}(w))$
    $= G^{*}(\eta)(F_{*}(v),F_{*}(w))$
    $= G^{*}F^{*}(\eta)(v,w)$

But this is absurd. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Set $\bar\eta := G^*(\eta)$. What is $\bar \eta (F_*(v), F_*(w))$?

Comment: Ah! I see. Thank you for hint.